# jQuery Validate extension method not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am adding the rule below to an existing jQuery Validate script using [`extension`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension), but this snippet causes it to break and not validate at all. I have tried every possible combination of commas before and after, and I have also tried using the [`accept`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#mimetype) method with mimetypes, but nothing thus far has worked. If I comment out this snippet (and the comment on the line before it), the code works perfectly, but adding this in causes it to break.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU3zf/) with the code as-is (doesn't work), and [here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/xVhun/1/) with exactly the same code except the snippet is commented out (works fine).

The snippet itself:

```
form1upload: {
    extension: "jpg|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|png"
}
```

The full code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#grantapp").validate({
        errorClass:"errorlabels",
        rules: {
            form1name: "required",
            form1building: "required",
            form1position: "required",
            form1phonex: "required",
            form1besttime: "required",
            form1projtitle: "required",
            form1benefit: "required",
            form1timeframe: "required",
            form1relevance: "required",
            form1description: "required",
            form1amount: "required",
            form1acceptchk: "required",
            form1upload: {
                extension: "jpg|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|png"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            form1name: "You must enter your name.",
            form1building: "You must enter your building.",
            form1position: "You must enter your position.",
            form1phonex: "You must enter your phone extension.",
            form1besttime: "You must enter the best time to contact you.",
            form1projtitle: "You must give your project a title.",
            form1benefit: "You must enter the number of students who will benefit.",
            form1timeframe: "You must enter a time frame for this project.",
            form1relevance: "<br />You must state how this project is relevant to education.",
            form1description: "<br />You must provide a description of your project.",
            form1amount: "You must enter a requested amount.",
            form1acceptchk: "<span style=\"position:relative;top:-10px;\">You must accept the terms.</span>",
            form1upload: "You may not upload this type of file."
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
            if (element.attr("name") == "form1acceptchk") {
                error.insertAfter("#tbl1");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I have checked it repeatedly and it looks good to me. The specific extension section looks correct as well, [according to the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension).

Comment: Tested with multiple versions of the plugin and it really seems broken http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/4jMHZ/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, it's not broken. It's just not a valid rule/method without first including the `additional-methods.js` file.

Comment: @Sparky Makes perfect sense. I'd expect for an error to be thrown for invalid rule but jQuery validate is too permissive.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, it does throw an error, not much different than any other piece of fictional code.  However, the programmer is expected to use proper syntax and know the method exists, that's our job.  I'll concede the documentation could be better, [but in this case, right above the "extension" link, it specifically says, _"Some more methods are provided as addons, currently included in `additional-methods.js` in the download package."_](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: @Sparky It does? I don't see any error being thrown in the fiddle I linked above.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, click "submit" and look at your console.

Comment: @Sparky Erm guess I overlooked that one last night. Thanks for the clean up.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, not a problem.  ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's because [the `extension` rule/method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension) is not part of the jQuery Validate plugin by default.

You must include the jQuery Validate plugin's [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) if you want to use the `extension` rule.

It seems to be working now...

http://jsfiddle.net/tMRer/

Comment: Didn't realize that was even a thing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note: the library has since been updated and additional-methods.js has been split up. Look for the extension.js file.

Comment: @Marcel, [where do you see that?](https://jqueryvalidation.org)  I think you might be confusing the fact that the developer also makes all methods available on GitHub as separate files.   Otherwise, [`extension` is still part of the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js).

Comment: Just looking at their github repo :)

Comment: @Marcel, that has always been the case.  That does not mean the method was removed from anything or that additional-methods has been split apart.